# NodeJS Express web scraping header issues

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am scraping a fan site for character info to display in my web app, but I am running into `Cant Set headers after they are sent.` I am trying to use promises during my request, but I think I may have a fundamental misunderstanding of what my code is actually doing.

The end goal is to scrape 100ish pages for data by looping through an array of boss names, store that data in an array, then eventually export it to use later. Currently I am able to store the data in an array, but still getting errors even though my code executes and scrapes the data.

server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var app = express();
var rp = require('request-promise');
var fsp = require('fs-promise');

app.get('/', function(req, res){

  urls = [
    'fansite/boss1', 'fansite/boss2'
  ];

  var bosses = [];

  function parse(html) {

    var $ = cheerio.load(html);

    $('.page-header__title').filter(function () {
      var data = $(this);
      name = data.text();
      bosses.push(name);
    })
    console.log(bosses);
    return bosses;
  }

  urls.forEach(function (url) {
    rp(url)
    .then(parse)
    .then(res.send('Bosses Updated.'))  
    .catch(err => console.log('Error:', err));
  });
})

app.listen('8081')
console.log('Running on port 8081');
exports = module.exports = app;
```

Output:

```
node server.js start
Running on port 8081
[ 'Obor' ]
[ 'Obor', 'Zulrah' ]
Error: Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:356:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (/Users/aaron/Personal Projects/node-scraper/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:767:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (/Users/aaron/Personal Projects/node-scraper/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:170:12)
    at rp.then.then (/Users/aaron/Personal Projects/node-scraper/server.js:31:21)
    at tryCatcher (/Users/aaron/Personal Projects/node-scraper/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/Users/aaron/Personal Projects/node-scraper/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:512:31)
    at Promise._settlePromise (/Users/aaron/Personal Projects/node-scraper/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:569:18)
    at Promise._settlePromise0 (/Users/aaron/Personal Projects/node-scraper/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:614:10)
    at Promise._settlePromises (/Users/aaron/Personal Projects/node-scraper/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:693:18)
    at Async._drainQueue (/Users/aaron/Personal Projects/node-scraper/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:133:16)
    at Async._drainQueues (/Users/aaron/Personal Projects/node-scraper/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:143:10)
    at Immediate.Async.drainQueues (/Users/aaron/Personal Projects/node-scraper/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:17:14)
    at runCallback (timers.js:672:20)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:645:5)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:617:5)
```

Comment: `.then` expects a function as the argument, you are providing the result of calling `res.send('Bosses Updated.')` as the argument - though, I can't see that this would cause the error you are describing - i.e. your code would `res.send('Bosses Updated.')` twice, immediately, before `parse` is even called - quick fix ... `.then(() => res.send('Bosses Updated.'))` - but, again, I can't see how this would help with your issue to be honest

Comment: @JaromandaX It is confusing me too, thanks for the tip about the Bosses Updated line, that makes sense. I will update my answer with some output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Promise.all` and catch individual request so you don't loose the successful ones. Report back in the response after Promise.all (all the requests are finished) with a response:

```
const Fail = function(reason){this.reason=reason;};
const isFail = x=>(x&&x.constructor)===Fail;
const isNotFail = x=>!isFail(x);
Promise.all(
  urls.map(
    url=>
      rp(url)
      .then(parse)
      .catch(err => new Fail([url,err]))
  )
)
.then(
  results=>
    res.json(results)
);
```

If you are making many requests to a site you may want to limit requests. Either by how many open requests you are making or how many requests you want to make within a certain time period. You can do this with [throttling](https://github.com/amsterdamharu/lib/blob/master/src/index.js) but if your express application is a public site where potentially many users can start the scraping you'd better make sure not to have the target site see your scraping as an attack.

```
const max = throttle(8)//maximum 8 open connections
//const max = throttlePeriod(8,1000);//maximum 8 requests per second
Promise.all(
  urls.map(
    url=>
      max(rp)(url)//throttle requests made
      .then(parse)
      .catch(err => new Fail([url,err]))
  )
)
.then(
  results=>
    res.send(JSON.parse)
)
```

Comment: I did not think of possibly needing to throttle my requests, as I will be making near 100. Thanks! I think I will probably implement your solution, but currently, after the promise I am going to send the json to an output file, but I am getitng duplicate data using 
`.then(
    results =>
      fsp.writeFile('output.json', JSON.stringify(results, null, 4))
  )` any ideas?

Comment: @Aaron Throttling depends on the site you are scraping. Some won't allow it and will block your ip for a while when making too many requests. If you're using [this writeFile](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback) it should replace the existing file, that means your scraping produced duplicate records. Maybe some pages have a different url but same data?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to wait for all the urls to be processed before sending a response

```
Promise.all(urls.map(function (url) {
  return rp(url).then(parse);
}))
.then(() => res.send('Bosses Updated.'))  
.catch(err => console.log('Error:', err));
```

or

```
Promise.all(urls.map(url => rp(url).then(parse)))
.then(() => res.send('Bosses Updated.'))  
.catch(err => console.log('Error:', err));
```

Comment: `I am scraping a fan site` and `The end goal is to scrape 100ish pages`. This would suggest it's better to do `Promise.all(p.catch(Fail)).then(result=>Fail,notFail)` so you don't loose the entire result on one failure

Comment: well, yes, of course - the error handling semantics are irrelevant :p

Answer (score 1):

`res.send` sends an entire HTTP response to the client, including headers and content, which is why you are unable to call it multiple times.